# Azure Cosmos DB analytical store: How can I view the Well-defined schema representation?

Tags: azure-synapse-link

Per the documentation on Analytical store.

[What is Azure Cosmos DB Analytical Store?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction)

“The first non-null occurrence defines the column data type. Any document not following the first non-null datatype won't be represented in analytical store.”

I want to confirm my DateTime columns are interpreted as DateTime and not stored as string.

How can I view the Well-defined schema representation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. SQL Serverless:

a) Create a view say MyView that gets the data.

b) Run the following against that view.

```
sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'select * from MyView where 1=0'
```

2. Spark:  df.printSchema